# path for googlecl

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I recently installed googlecl (to access google calendar from the command line) on Mac OS X 10.5.8, and it was working fine when I installed it.

After that I installed other programs (don't remember which ones exactly). However, today when I tried to access google from the command line, I got the error

```
-bash: google: command not found
```

I suppose the path got deleted. Does anyone know what I have to add to the path to get google command to work again. Is it possible, something else went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

use `find / -name "google" -type f` to find the path where googlecl is installed. Then, add that path to your `PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile` or `.profile`

Answer (score 1):

Try `locate google` before `find`. `locate` is a ton faster than `find` because it searches a database rather than the filesystem. However, if the database has not been updated since you installed the files, `locate` won't know about them.

Even easier would likely be to look at how you installed it. If you used MacPorts, then use `port contents PORT_NAME` to find out what all was installed by the port. If you used an installer package, then look either in `/var/log/install.log` to see where it installed things, or look at the package receipt in `/var/db/receipts/` (`lsbom` will likely come in handy).

Once you know where it was installed, you can update your `PATH`: add a line to your `.profile` that exports a new `PATH`, and then `source ~/.profile`.

It's likely it got installed to a normal place, so it might just magically work if you add this line to your `.profile` and then `source ~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sw/bin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```